# Redis - Monit does not start properly

Tags: redis, monit

Monit can not start redis-server properly.

#### Running Redis through `init.d` *works correctly*:

```
$ sudo su

$ /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start

$ #=> Starting Redis server...

$ ps aux | grep redis

$ #=> root      8980  0.0  0.0  42128  1964 ?        Ssl  04:56   0:00 /etc/redis/src/redis-server *:6379

$ /etc/init.d/redis_6379 stop

$ #=> Stopping ...

$ #=> Redis stopped

$ #=> (ps aux| grep redis) There's no redis process.
```

#### Running Redis through `Monit` *does not work correctly*:

(I killed the Redis process and `rm /var/run/redis_6379.pid`)

```
$ sudo su

$ monit start redis

$ ps aux | grep redis

$ #=> root      9082  0.0  0.0  35076  1972 ?        Ssl  05:08   0:00 /etc/redis/src/redis-server *:6379
```

monit.log:

```
[MSK Jan  6 05:08:14] info     : 'redis' start on user request
[MSK Jan  6 05:08:14] info     : monit daemon at 3947 awakened
[MSK Jan  6 05:08:14] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[MSK Jan  6 05:08:14] info     : 'redis' start: /etc/init.d/redis_6379
[MSK Jan  6 05:08:44] error    : 'redis' failed to start
[MSK Jan  6 05:08:44] info     : 'redis' start action done
```

#### Stopping Redis through Monit *does not works correclty* also:

```
$ ps aux | grep redis

$ #=> root      9018  0.0  0.0  35076  1968 ?        Ssl  05:02   0:00 /etc/redis/src/redis-server *:6379

$ monit stop redis

$ ps aux | grep redis

$ #=> root      9082  0.0  0.0  35076  1972 ?        Ssl  05:08   0:00 /etc/redis/src/redis-server *:6379
```

monit.log

```
[MSK Jan  6 05:10:02] info     : 'redis' stop on user request
[MSK Jan  6 05:10:02] info     : monit daemon at 3947 awakened
[MSK Jan  6 05:10:02] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[MSK Jan  6 05:10:02] info     : 'redis' stop action done
```

#### I have:

- Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
- redis-2.8.2
- monit-5.3.2
- redis instalation path /etc/redis
- monit instalation path /etc/monit (installed from apt-get repo)

#### And following config files:

https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/665112df34d2eae09330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changes owner of `/etc/redis dir`

```
$ chown -R root /etc/redis
```

and restart monit

```
$ monit restart
```

The problem is gone. Strange. I wish it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and there is no mutch talk about this situation around. I fixed it with another solution, it may concern someone else so I post it here.

in monit configuration file I had

```
start program = "/etc/init.d/redis start"
stop  program = "/etc/init.d/redis stop"
```

Replacing by the following fixed the problem (with Ubuntu)

```
start program = "/usr/sbin/service redis start"
stop  program = "/usr/sbin/service redis stop"
```